# ASP.Net Web Deployment Project Merge Errors

Tags: asp.net, merge, web-deployment-project, aspnet-merge

I get this error:

Duplicate type 'powerstats_Admin_control' found in assembly 'App_Web_ssek9ymk'. aspnet_merge    1   1   Release3

I know that its unique to my system but how do I fix it?  What does it mean?

**ANSWER:**
http://forums.asp.net/t/942008.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in the ASP.Net temporary files - `c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\Temporary ASP.NET Files` and clear that out (change the path for the relevant framework version).

Comment: can't seem to find the temporary files folder anywhere under any of the framework folders

Comment: Ah - I have them listed under v1.1, 2.0 and 4.0. What version of ASP.Net are you developing in/for?

Comment: i don't have it under any, i think the version is 3.5

Comment: I'm afraid that's all I can think of. If I have any other pearls of wisdom, I'll pass them on.

Comment: Very interesting - the perils of making it easy to move things hey!